# Bootstrap stretch contents on entire screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for responsive design.

I want contents to auto-fill depend on the screen size (Which bootstrap allows in-built). Although it is not working when I am connecting to the big monitor (22 inch)

See as below:

**Picture 1 (on my Laptop); Covers the entire screen**

[image]

**Picture 2 on Big Monitor (Notice the empty area in the bottom)**
(Between Header 6 and End of Browser window)
[image]

I expect Headers and contents will be displayed big to cover the entire screen

[image]

HTML as below:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" >
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td><img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="Images/Logo.png"></td>
<td align="right"><img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="Images/Header_RequestExpress.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
<div class="row"  style="border:1px solid; color:Red;">
    <div class="col-md-4"  style="border:1px solid; color:green;">
        <h2>Categories</h2>
         <!--Images Carousel Here-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row"  style="border:1px solid; color:blue;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Locations</h2>
           <!--Images Carousel Here-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"  style="border:1px solid; color:Maroon;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Location Current Requests</h2>
            <h1>Header 1</h1>
                 <h2>Header 2</h2>
                  <h3>Header 3</h3>
                   <h4>Header 4</h4>
                    <h5>Header 5</h5>
                     <h6>Header 6</h6>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `height:100vh;`to the container div.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, on your laptop it was just lucky to appear that way, with the content you filled as you didn't put any rule for the page to be full-height.

You either have to proportion `.table` and `.row` vertically.

Example:

```
.table {
    height: 30vh;
}

.row {
    height: 70vw;
}
```

Or let's say the `table` height is `100px` and you want the other part to be filled for the rest of the screen, you can apply:

```
.table {
    height: 200px;
}

.row {
    height: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

**NOTE** I'd suggest you add another class as well to the div `.row` as that class can be used other places as well, as the Bootstrap provides it.

Comment: tx Ardian. I got the idea! Being back-end developer front end development is always confusing

Comment: Haha, I get it. Didn't this do what you were looking for?